# React - native developement server return response error code : 500

Tags: react-native

I'm building an application in react-native, everything was working fine .After `npm install`, react-native doesn't detect some of my files anymore saying it doesnt exist, doesn't seem to detect any changes either. I get

`` "Developpement server returned response error 500, unable to resolve module `../services/myFile` none of these files exist." on android and on IOS 'Failed to load Bundle with error: "unable to resolve module ./screens/anotherFile" ``

When I remove those files (from the files they are use in) the error is still the same. Any ideas ?

Comment: did you link module using `react-native-link` ? Also please share some code or directory structure, it will help community to solve your issue quicker !

Comment: Thx for your reply ! I didn't do it again after npm install, now it's working fine thanks !!

Comment: cool, happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

Like @firu said, make sure you do a `react-native-link`, this happens if you have deleted the `ios` or `android` folder. Most cases when you are upgrading react-native with `react-native-upgrade`